# Cancan permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

I have a rails app that is is using cancan permission and i am trying to block others users from editing another user's dashboard. This has worked for other models but not this one.

**profile.rb**

```
belongs_to :dashboard
```

**Dashboard.rb**

```
has_many :profiles
```

**Dashboard_controller**

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
load_and_authorize_resource :through => :current_profile
```

**Ability.rb**

```
can :manage, Dashboard, :profile => { :user_id => user.id }
```

When I go to view my dashboard rails gives me the error

> undefined method `dashboards'

Any ideas how I can overcome this error?

Full trace

```
    activemodel (3.1.3) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:385:in `method_missing'
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:60:in `method_missing'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:174:in `resource_base'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:77:in `load_collection?'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:33:in `load_resource'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
cancan (1.6.7) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:439:in `_run__4465164984821190291__process_action__669795061578511304__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:247:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.1.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: What's the full error?  I'm attempting to recreate the issue, but haven't been successful yet.

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `dashboards' for #<Profile:0x007f8f6d65de80>)

Comment: Does the view or layout contain a call to `profile.dashboards` that should be `profile.dashboard? Maybe a typo?

Comment: @iltempo sounds like he's on the right track.  Do you have the full stack trace of where this was thrown?  This will definitely help find the error.  It doesn't sound like it's coming from cancan at the moment.

Comment: @philt5252 I have added full trace above to description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `load_authorize_resource` Cancan assumes a plural resource (ie that a profile has many dashboards). According to the docs adding `:singleton => true` turns this off

Comment: Guess that was the problem, thank you! I was stuck on this for 2 days